# Is there a way to kill all forked threads in a GHCi session without restarting it?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc, yesod, ghcid

Based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998600/what-happens-to-child-threads-when-their-parent-dies-in-ghc-haskell/24998897) I'd like to ask if there's any way to kill all *user created* threads in a GHCi session?

The reason for this is that when a function exits in GHCi the threads that it spawned don't terminate automatically, persisting even through code reloads. Restarting GHCi solves this, but since my application takes a while to load, it would be great if there was a possible (even hacky) workaround.

Comment: Depends. Do all your modules load `Control.Concurrent`, or do you have a single module which bundles all used functions? If the latter is true, you could provide a user-written `forkIO` which collects all ThreadIds in an `MVar [ThreadId]`. Then it's as simple as `takeMVar m >>= mapM killThread >> putMVar m []`.

Comment: I wish I could, but my problem comes from using Yesod, which has it's own threading stuff built in.

Comment: Actually, every evaluation you type into GHCi is done in another thread. Try `myThreadId` several times. I guess this is also a reason [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/369198/michael-snoyman) wrote `yesod devel`: there is no `killAllNRestart` in GHCi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and actually for almost the same reasons as in [How can I build a ThreadId given that I know the actual number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995262/how-can-i-build-a-threadid-given-that-i-know-the-actual-number): The library simply doesn't give you anything to get the `ThreadId`s of all (still running) threads or any other facility to work on any threads which doesn't belong to you.

Furthermore, you cannot reliably  guess which threads spawned with `forkIO` belong to your GHCi session (all evaluations are usually sandboxed in `forkIO`), the underlying yesod application, or to the threaded RTS (which has at least one call to `forkIO` - which basically ensures that all event managers get shut down). Currently, this isn't too bad, since GHCi runs in the `main` thread and the IO manager gets restarted if shut down anyway, but that could change in future versions.

So why do threads even get collected on termination? [`hs_exit()`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/c1336f71dbd80b66643e65fc7d5df0cc8fe9942b/rts/RtsStartup.c#L305-L437). Essentially, it calls `ioManagerDie()` (killing all [event managers](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/IOManager)) and `exitScheduler(..)` (see [scheduler](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Scheduler), which basically [kills all threads](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f6866824ce5cdf5359f0cad78c49d65f6d43af12/rts/Schedule.c#L2463-L2488). None of those functions have an appropriate FFI wrapper.

At the time `hs_exit()` is called, the `main` from the Haskell world has already finished. Since none of those functions have an appropriate equivalent in the `GHC.*` modules, you cannot call them directly in Haskell and therefore in GHCi, since there isn't an appropriate `:#` command.

So all in all, you can't. If one would add a command to restart the scheduler in GHCi, it would be easy as pie. But given that the scheduler gets started in `hs_init()` and stopped in `hs_exit()` in the [RTS model](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts), I doubt that this would be a easy extension.

---

Depending on what you want to do, you can however cheat. You can write your own `forkIOMem`, which stores the `ThreadId` in a global `MVar`, and replace all of `forkIO` in the sources. That can be *very* cumbersome, especially if you're working with a library, since you need to ensure that `forkIO` is replaced *everywhere*.

You could, of course, meddle with the `base` package, but that's probably madness (still possible though), change `forkIO` there and add `killAllforkIOs` to `Control.Concurrent`. <sup>(I've already said that this is probably madness, right?)</sup>

Comment: Avoiding `forkIO` entirely by using something like `Control.Concurrent.Async.race_` (which does kill the other thread) for instance is another trick to approach this problem.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Yeah, but that's a) an external package and b) isn't applicable in this instance, as the threads in OP's scenario were `forkIO`ed by Yesod.

Answer (score 1):

As of `base-4.18` you can do:

```
GHC.Conc.listThreads >>= mapM_ GHC.Conc.killThread
```